# What's the state of a lambda in java (lambda stateful vs stateless)

Tags: java, lambda, state

In OCP : a stateful lambda expression is one whose result depends on any state might change during the execution of the pipeline (parralelStream).
Then they said this operation contain a stateful lambda expression :

```
...
.map(i->{data.add(i);return i;}) //stateful lambda
...
```

Where the state has changed ? No operation is apply on the variable "i"

Comment: In here: `data.add(i)`

Answer (score 1):

`data.add(i)` sounds like a stateful operation, it has the name add, which implies mutability.

When run in parallel if data is an ordered list, you have no guarantee on which order the elements will be received, and depending on if data is threadsafe, cause errors.